# Git check if there is outstanding commits to push

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a command I can run to check if there is any commits to push to origin/master?

```
git [some command] origin master
```

Would output something like:

```
origin/master is behind by 7 commits
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two ways to list the "extra" commits you have which are not on origin/master:

```
git log --oneline origin/master..HEAD
git rev-list --oneline ^origin/master HEAD
```

The `--oneline` just lists them in a shorter format.  Also, if your branch tracks origin/master, a simple `git status` will show you.

Answer (score 5):

```
git diff --stat master origin/master
```

Example output:

```
classes/Mammoth/Article.php                                            |   12 ++++++++++--
classes/Mammoth/Article/Admin/Section/Controller.php                   |   34 +++++++++++++++++-----------------
classes/Mammoth/Article/Filter.php                                     |   14 +++++++-------
classes/Mammoth/Article/Section.php                                    |   18 ++++++++++--------
classes/Mammoth/Article/Section/IMySQL.php                             |    2 +-
migrations/20130411111424_ChangeNameToURIOnSectionsTable.php           |   14 --------------
migrations/sql/up/20130411111424_ChangeNameToURIOnSectionsTable.sql    |    5 -----
solr-core/conf/schema.xml                                              |    2 +-
views/admin/section/form.php                                           |    8 ++++----
views/admin/section/view.php                                           |   10 +++++-----
10 files changed, 55 insertions(+), 64 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're up-to-date with your fetching (something all the other answers here presume as well)

```
$ git checkout
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

To get that info for all branches,

```
$ git branch -avvv
```

Comment: Is it really needed to be up-to-date with the fetching?  One would still get told that we're having unpushed commits, no matter how much the upstream repo has changed ...  the only exception I can think of is if one pushes the changesets to another node, and then pushes the changeset from the other node and upstream ... now upstream is in sync with the local repo, but without "fetch" one wouldn't know ... hm :-)

Comment: @tobixen also forced pushes and recovery from backup.  If  Murphy doesn't look like an innocent skipping through the fields of daisies, I'm not being paranoid enough. The computing version of the law is "if anything can go wrong, it has already gone wrong, and wants your blood."

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to solve this goes like this:

```
git push --all -n 2>&1 | grep -q 'Everything up-to-date' || 
echo "Outstanding commits to be pushed at $PWD"
```

It's not robust, as it will claim there are outstanding commits on errors.  The biggest problem is that it will ask for username/password i.e. if attempting to push to a github repo with https-link (typically because I did a RO checkout on some repo where I'm not supposed to directly push changes).

The jtill answer seems to fit me the best, as it contains instructions on how to check this for all branches.  Hence my second attempt looks like this:

```
 git branch -avvv 2>&1 | grep -q ': ahead ' && 
   echo "Outstanding commits to be pushed at $PWD"
```

However, this also have at least one caveat - there will be false positives if a commit message contains the string ': ahead '.

So then I have this command for "check the status of all the git repos":

```
for gitrepo in $(find ~ -name '.git')
do 
    cd $(dirname $gitrepo)
    git fetch >/dev/null 2>&1 || 
      echo "Git fetch failed at $PWD"
    git branch -avvv 2>&1 | grep -q ': ahead ' &&
      echo "Outstanding commits to be pushed at $PWD"
done
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you wanted as it looks for the same thing "git status" shows as changes. But Google brought your post up when I was searching for this info.

This little shell script for linux will tell you if there is something changed but only if it is not yet committed.

```
if [[ "$(git status --porcelain)" != "" ]]; then
  echo "there are changes that should be committed and pushed"
fi
```

As regards committed changes, the accepted answer works for main branch or if you know the branch name you care about. This will work for commits in the current branch and show a count of the commits:

```
git log --oneline origin..HEAD | wc -l
```

Output might be:

```
2
```